# Should Programmers participate in Winter Bash 2014?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, fun, hats, winterbash

Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard.

This event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on winterbash2014.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Programmers has participated in this event in the past. Should we participate again this year?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Do we want hats?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5240/25768)

Comment: Are you sure we can't keep the hats? Pretty Please?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### HATS!!!! <sup>*</sup>

<sup>*</sup><sub>'nuff said</sub>

Comment: *(Need more characters to post)

Answer (score 1):

Devil's Advocate post...

### NO HATS!!!

[image]